# How do I find what day the last saturday of the current month is in PHP?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

This works for most months, but for example, April 2011 has 5 saturdays, so this returns 23 instead of 30.

```
$last_saturday = date("j", strtotime('Fourth Saturday'.date('F o')));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`last saturday` seems to be interpreted as "previous saturday" in some constellations.

This is what works for me on PHP 5.3 on Windows 7: Jump to next month's first day, and look for last saturday.

```
 $nextMonthStart = mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+1,1,date('Y'));
 $last_saturday = date("d.m.Y",strtotime("previous saturday", $nextMonthStart));
```

works for me even in the edge case that the first day of next month is a saturday.

Answer (score 10):

Interestingly enough, `strtotime("last saturday of this month")` does exactly that.

See [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for more, particularly the section on [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: `strtotime()` uses actual magic in its source code. It can do all things.

Comment: Apparently not for me, it is returning 31, and there obviously isn't an April 31.

Comment: @JamesSimpson: Try printing out the entire date, e.g. with the `r` format.

Comment: It's working here. `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last saturday of this month"));` nicely outputs `2011-04-30`.

Comment: @Anne not for me (returns null, PHP 5.3 on Windows 7)

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? That returns 1969-12-31, so trtotime("last saturday of this month") is returning nothing. I'm running 5.2.9 on CentOS.

Comment: I'm running 5.3.3 on Mac OSX 10.6.6.

Comment: @James @Anne this PHP bug *might* be related. Not sure. http://bugs.php.net/51096

Comment: @Pekka: Not *all* things. For example, it gets "2010-Apr-9" wrong, even though it does get "2010-4-9" correct.

Comment: @Anomie yeah. Plus I was too hasty, what you quote doesn't work for me at all on Windows. Strange!

Comment: @Pekka: Reports are that "xxx day of" was added in PHP 5.3. This is unfortunately *not* documented on PHP's website.

Comment: @Anomie ah, that stinks! `strtotime()` is badly documented anyway if you want to know about the finer points.

Answer (score 1):

These days people use `strtotime` too liberally... if you want to be real hardcore (and reinvent the wheel a bit) you can use this piece of code I wrote for [Moodle](http://www.moodle.org) back in the day, which I guess has some novelty value. I copied it from [here](http://cvs.moodle.org/moodle/lib/moodlelib.php?revision=1.1524&view=markup).

The last Sunday of April 2011 is `find_day_in_month(-1, 0, 4, 2011)`, which means "start searching from the last day of April 2011 backwards and tell me when the first Sunday you find is".

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/h7Uhr).

```
/**
 * Calculate the number of days in a given month
 *
 * @param int $month The month whose day count is sought
 * @param int $year The year of the month whose day count is sought
 * @return int
 */
function days_in_month($month, $year) {
   return intval(date('t', mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)));
}


/**
 * ?
 *
 * @todo Document what this function does
 * @param int $startday Defines the day from which to start searching (absolute value) and the direction in which to search (sign)
 * @param int $weekday -1 if you don't want the function to match a specific weekday; 0 to 6 to match specific weekdays
 * @param int $month The month wherein the day is sought
 * @param int $year The year wherein the day is sought
 * @return int
 */
function find_day_in_month($startday, $weekday, $month, $year) {
    $daysinmonth = days_in_month($month, $year);

    if($weekday == -1) {
        // Don't care about weekday, so return:
        //    abs($startday) if $startday != -1
        //    $daysinmonth otherwise
        return ($startday == -1) ? $daysinmonth : abs($startday);
    }

    // From now on we 're looking for a specific weekday

    // Give "end of month" its actual value, since we know it
    if($startday == -1) {
        $startday = -1 * $daysinmonth;
    }

    // Starting from day $startday, the sign is the direction

    if($startday < 1) {

        $startday = abs($startday);
        $lastmonthweekday  = strftime('%w', mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $daysinmonth, $year));

        // This is the last such weekday of the month
        $lastinmonth = $daysinmonth + $weekday - $lastmonthweekday;
        if($lastinmonth > $daysinmonth) {
            $lastinmonth -= 7;
        }

        // Find the first such weekday <= $startday
        while($lastinmonth > $startday) {
            $lastinmonth -= 7;
        }

        return $lastinmonth;

    }
    else {

        $indexweekday = strftime('%w', mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $startday, $year));

        $diff = $weekday - $indexweekday;
        if($diff < 0) {
            $diff += 7;
        }

        // This is the first such weekday of the month equal to or after $startday
        $firstfromindex = $startday + $diff;

        return $firstfromindex;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

$date = Carbon::now();
$date = $date->lastOfMonth(Carbon::SATURDAY);
echo 'last saturday = '.$date->day;
```

Answer (score -2):

$lastSaturDay=   date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last saturday of this month'));