# How to find out last wednesday of month in PHP for PHP version 5.1.6

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Is there any way in PHP to find out the last Wednesday of the current month? (or any day of the week for that matter)

For instance, the last Wednesday of this month (February 2014) is February 26, 2014

I know this would echo "February 2014"

```
echo date( 'F Y', strtotime( 'this month'));
```

This is my pseudo-code that doesn't work (it echoes "31 December 1969"):

```
echo date( 'd F Y', strtotime( 'last wednesday of this month'));
```

Any way to make this happen?

Comment: Works fine for me http://viper-7.com/YNqC83 what PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Petah: PHP version 5.1.6

Comment: @StephaniAlves `5.1.*` is long outdated and you should upgrade.

Comment: @Petah I can't update it, company won't let me.

Comment: Have you tried using the `modify` method of `DateTime`?

Comment: How about some basic maths? Get the last month day day of week the subtract?

Comment: @Yani: they use php 5.1

Comment: @StephaniAlves that is ridiculous and extremely insecure. I fell sorry for you.

Comment: @Petah: insecure? Any real security issues found in 5.1.6+?

Comment: @zerkms http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-36749/PHP-PHP-5.1.6.html

Comment: @Petah: it's funny - according to that list all versions are affected by something. So it's extremely insecure to use php. TBH, 99% of those CVE require some really stupid code without any validation and data sanitizing.

Comment: "of this month" seems to not be supported prior to PHP 5.3: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#98989

Comment: @zerkms I do not see any `5.5.9` vulnerabilities, also note that there is are 10 publicly available exploits for `5.1.6` in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tsLast = strtotime( date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month')).' last wednesday');
echo date(DATE_RFC850, $tsLast);
```

Comment: This worked. I just changed the format a bit from 'Y-m-01' to 'd F Y' and got what I wanted. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: works, over-complication. Relative Formats will let you specify last week of current month. See my answer

Comment: Its not giving correct output.. it produces 2014-02-25 which is Tuesday not Wednesday

Comment: @Atul that's odd, I see it giving correct output for 5.1.6: http://3v4l.org/59WRr . Although I can't see why it would matter, is your machine's clock set correctly to local time?

Comment: I checked using phpfiddle so yaa may be..

Answer (score 0):

`echo Date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Wednesday of F'));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It probably works on the newer versions of PHP. For me, this code gives me "1969-12-31" (I believe the problem is my PHP version 5.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
  $nextMonthStart = mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+1,1,date('Y'));
  $last_wednesday = date("d F Y",strtotime("previous wednesday", $nextMonthStart)); 
  echo $last_wednesday;
```

got it from here: [How do I find what day the last saturday of the current month is in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767561/how-do-i-find-what-day-the-last-saturday-of-the-current-month-is-in-php)

Comment: actually you don't even need to figure out the next month and go back. Relative formats will let you do 'last Wednesday of F'. See my (edited) answer